# Configuring MPIO on Windows to remove duplicate disks

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage-area-network, fibre-channel, mpio

We have shared some storage from a EMC Unity SAN to Windows Server 2012 R2 to use with Veeam. In Disk Management, there are multiple disks listed with the same size.  From previous systems, this is because of Multi-Pathing.

I have enabled the MPIO Feature and added some devices, but still it lists multiple disks. EMC provide the app PowerPath, which I have installed a trial of, but surely I don't need that to get this working!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK without PowerPath you'll have only active-passive link failover without load balancing.
Maybe it's working already, although multiple drives are shown in device manager. It's worth trying to disconnect some paths in test environment.

Comment: Installing PowerPath initially did nothing much. I have eventually for it working, but I couldn't tell you what fixed it. That's for another time so I can answer this question properly...